# Autoit click with OK button not happening with Windows 10

Tags: ui-automation, autoit, windows-10

After loading a URL a pop up window with title "Device window" occurs which has one"OK" button, when i try to click on it its not happening with Enter/Mouse-click/Control-click. need to know if it works with Windows 10 on IE 11 browser or is there any other way to perform this action

```
_WinWaitActivate("Device window","")
Sleep(25000)
Send("{ENTER}")
MouseClick("left",976, 630,1,5)


Sleep(10000)
if (ControlGetText("Device window","OK",1) = "OK") Then
ControlClick("Device window","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
MsgBox(1,"done","button exists")
EndIf
```

button exists message box appears, but Click action is not performed.

Comment: Does mouseclick moves the mouse on the coords you are pointing it to?

Comment: Yes it does. Moves over the click button but action is not performed.

Comment: Elevate your program. User #RequireAdmin

Comment: Which user account do you use in Win10? It may be the permission deny for your own user. So please enable administrator and try again. Please refer to this link. https://community.ivanti.com/thread/49951